# How to test fragment navigation in Espresso with Navigation Component (Fragment to Fragment)?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to test fragment navigation (from a fragment to another) when I click a button but in the test, it never navigates to the destination. 

When I test it manually it works correctly.

Also I'm using Navigation Component.

I researched and found a sample code from Google but I can't run it

**My Test:**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class OnBoardingFragmentTest{

@Test fun navigationTest(){
    val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<OnBoardingFragment>()
    onView(withId(R.id.btn_start)).perform(click())
}
```

**The code for the button click at Fragment:**

```
btn_start.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_onBoardingFragment_to_loginFragment)
}
```

**Sample from Google:**

I tried to use this sample from Google to test fragment navigation but I couldn't run it because mockito is not recognized (also tried with mockk library for kotlin).

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TitleScreenTest {

@Test
fun testNavigationToInGameScreen() {
    // Create a mock NavController
    val mockNavController = mock(NavController::class.java)

    // Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the TitleScreen
    val titleScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<TitleScreen>()

    // Set the NavController property on the fragment
    titleScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), mockNavController)
    }

    // Verify that performing a click prompts the correct Navigation action
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.play_btn)).perform(ViewActions.click())
    verify(mockNavController).navigate(R.id.action_title_screen_to_in_game)
}
```

**Error thrown at Test:**

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 835, 1565 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: tokencash.com.stx.tokencash:id/btn_start'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:86)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:87)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:59)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:322)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:178)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:119)
at tokencash.com.stx.OnBoardingFragmentTest.generalTest(OnBoardingFragmentTest.kt:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:531)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{3c7882 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1605} does not have a NavController set
at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
at tokencash.com.stx.tokencash.fragments.OnBoardingFragment$setListeners$1.onClick(OnBoardingFragment.kt:53)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:148)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:525)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:484)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:236)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:162)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:139)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:170)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:31)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:47)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:137)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:366)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:255)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:65)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:155)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Put the actions/assertions into the `onFragment {}` clause

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a lot of tests, I solved it.

To use navigation from a fragment to another inside a test you should mock a NavController. 

I was setting up incorrectly Mockito.

**Setup Mockito:***

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.24.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.24.5'
}
```

**Do static import in test**

```
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.verify
```

**And simple copy and paste Google Code**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TitleScreenTest {

@Test
fun testNavigationToInGameScreen() {
    // Create a mock NavController
    val mockNavController = mock(NavController::class.java)

    // Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the TitleScreen
    val titleScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<TitleScreen>()

    // Set the NavController property on the fragment
    titleScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), mockNavController)
    }

    // Verify that performing a click prompts the correct Navigation action
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.play_btn)).perform(ViewActions.click())
    verify(mockNavController).navigate(R.id.action_title_screen_to_in_game)
}
```

I hope it helps someone else ;)

Comment: thx a lot :) and please note you can accept your own answer (may improve search results for others)

Comment: That's great! I'm glad it was useful. Thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: Additionally, if you use androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin replace the R.id.action_xxx by TitleScreenDiretions.actionXxx() like the example below:

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).

Answer (score 0):

To whom is facing this exception "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant)." like I was when trying to run the above and is using kotlin the solution is to pass the themeResId when launching fragment.

It'd be something like this:

val titleScenario = launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.Theme_BillsNotifier)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33037121)

Comment: I tried to put this in comment stack above but I was not able to.  In the commemt stack above  Varun Chandran was facing an issue when running the code from the answer, and to solve that issue I was able tp do it using what i put in my answer. So my answer is a complememt to whom is facing an exception trying that code from answer above. Sorry for messing up if I did, was just trying to help